# Ghost tcp connections: ss sees them, nothing else does

Tags: tcp, netstat, conntrack

We have a strange problem. Our remote server shows over 900 connections coming from our office over port 80:

```
# ss -n | grep ESTAB | grep $OFFICEIP | grep :80 | wc -l
935
```

Netstat shows a similar number:

```
# netstat -n | grep $OFFICEIP | grep :80 | wc -l
922
```

(Although interestingly the netstat number periodically changes, either going up or down a bit.)

We simply cannot find where these connections are coming from. Our office router doesn't show them in its tables, and doing a tcpdump (`tcpdump -ieth1 -qnnvvSXs 1500 port 80`) on the remote host shows zero traffic on that port at all, let alone from our office ip.

In addition, conntrack doesn't show the connections as existing either:

```
# conntrack -L | grep $OFFICEIP | grep 80
conntrack v0.9.13 (conntrack-tools): 38025 flow entries have been shown.
```

This is happening on a box running CentOS 6, kernel version 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64. If anyone has any ideas as to where these discrepancies are coming from it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `| wc -l` to get the whole list and check the other side's IP? Also, I would recommend using `grep -F $OFFICEIP` instead, since the dot in grep (used without the `-F` flag) means "any character" and could be getting wrong results.

Comment: Our office is NAT'd, so the other side is always `$OFFICEIP`. I tried with the `-F`, it didn't make a difference though.

Comment: If the connections are over port 80, did the web server get any logs from it? `netstat -nap | grep -F $OFFICEIP | grep :80` should give you the process that is attending that connection, so you could either restart it (to force the connections to close) or check its logs.

Comment: Unfortunately the "connections" (or whatever they are) are already made, and I didn't have logging on back then so it's too late for that. And I can't restart it at the moment, I might try that later tonight though.

Comment: i have a similar problem, but more isolated. 2 rhel machines talking over a switch. one machine believes that it has M connection ESTABLISHED to the other, and that other lists N connections to the first machine. M does not equals N. This happened during stress-test during which the server sent [FIN], but the packets get lost sometimes, and if [FIN] didn't reach the client, server quickly kills FIN_WAIT state. This is what I believe happened. Default keepalive settings keep broken connections for hours...